# Generate random objects in Java

Tags: java, random, arraylist, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

im doing a performance review of graphdatabases in context of process modelling.
Therefore I set up a simple testcase which tracks the performance of simple inserts into the embedded N4J database. This is an excerpt of my testcase.

```
@Test
    public void insertQuants(){
        int size =750;
        /**
         * create 10 different languages and store them in the ArrayList
         */
        ArrayList<Language> lngs = new ArrayList<Language>();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            String title = "Testsprache " + String.valueOf(i);
            String description = "Beschreibung " +String.valueOf(i); 
            lngs.add(modelservice.createLanguage(title,description));
        }           
        /**
         * Create different models and assign them to different
         * language objects
         */
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            String title = "Testmodel " + String.valueOf(i);
            //get random between 0 and 9
            int fin = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*9);
            //fetch random Language object out of ArrayList
            Language l = lngs.get(fin);
            Model m = modelservice.createModel(l, title);
            l.addModel(m);
            template.save(l);
        }
```

the methods createModel in modelservice return the specific created object ( model or language ).
The issue i'm currently facing is that the random assigning of languages to models is not working. The Script assigns each model to one language object. In my mind it rather should randomly assign languages to model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the random assignment:

```
int fin = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*9);
```

`Math.random()` returns a `double` in range: `[0,1)`, multiplying by 9 gives: `[0,9)`, and rounding gives `[0,9]`.  As *CPerkins* pointed out, using `Random` may look simpler and is probably better (since the probability of generating numbers 0 through 9 is not uniform with your method), but your random number generation range is correct.  The issue is not in the code that you have shown us.  Perhaps it's in `addModel()` or `save()`.

Comment: I suggest that you do some more testing and once you have a more precise idea of what's going wrong, post another question if you can't resolve it.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I'll take a closer look to the addModel / save methods implemented

Comment: Code is working, it was just my lack of competency regarding the use of neoclipse to track nodes stored in n4j :) But i'll implement to changes to the random element for getting an uniform distribution of the numbers

Answer (score 1):

This isn't your problem, but it's **a** problem: Math.random returns a double between 0 and 1.   Multiplying that by 9 and rounding doesn't give you a fair distribution (zero and nine will appear only half as often as you'd want). Change:

```
int fin = (int) Math.round(Math.random()*9);
```

to something more like

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
...
int fin = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: How doesn't it?  9 * [0,1) = [0, 9).  Rounding gives [0,9]. Using `Random` looks simpler, but what he has works.

Comment: It's never 1. He'll get the 9th value less often than the other values, because there's no round-down.   .

Comment: Fair enough, this is true for 0, too. Edit your post.  The range is most definitely [0,9]; nonetheless, that's not his problem (he keeps getting the same number).